# Why does the usb audio latency change?

Tags: sound, usb, ardour

I'm a musician, not a programmer, so please try to tell me something as simply as possible.

Today's musicians are using USB audio interfaces. (Theese have dedicated drivers for Windows, and class compilant Core Audio for MAC)
BUT:
I really fell in love with Ubuntu Studio, i want to switch over it from windows,
but on Ardour (digital audio workstation) website i can read this:

"Almost all USB Audio Class 1 or 2 compliant devices (i.e. it comes without its own drivers for Windows, macOS or iOS) will work on Linux. Be aware that as of 2020, the audio latency for USB devices under Linux can change every time the device is re-used/restarted."

My question is : WHY ?

(By the way I found driver/control software source codes for my Focusrite 18i20, learned how to compile it, the test-computer started to communicate properly with my interface, and booom... Latency changes always a little bit, my recorded multitracks were out of sync. Say no more, being out of sync in music is a huge problem.)

Can anyone explain me, is Ubuntu today able to make music or not ???

Thank You!
Best regards,
Patrik

Comment: My opinion is that it is not a great idea to use Ubuntu for making music. It is possible to setup certain devices, but it is not worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

The latency of a USB audio device can change for a number of reasons. The most common reason is that the device is sharing a USB bus with other devices, and the amount of available bandwidth can fluctuate. This can cause the audio to sound choppy or distorted. Another reason can be that the drivers for the device are not optimized for low latency, which can also cause audio issues.